# Laravel Footer Information

Tags: php, laravel

My laravel app is showing this information (from Barryvdh Debugbar) at the bottom of the page. How can I remove them? Kindly help!
[Laravel App Foot Notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYecZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

That's a package called [Laravel DebugBar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar), if as you said, **want to remove it** you should uninstall it using composer:

```
composer remove barryvdh/laravel-debugbar
```

Also remember to remove from your `config/app.php` the following lines:

```
// Declared in your server providers
Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class

// Declared in your aliases
'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class
```

After everything is clean I would recommend you to run `composer dumpautoload` to prevent future errors. Also in case you already cached your application, you should run `php artisan config:cache` as some of the changes made in `config/app.php` stays in cache.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @VincentBii You're very welcome, if this solved your question, please, consider accepting it as an answer so other people can find it easly.